# How to fix: "MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::getInt: invalid value of 'columnIndex"

Tags: c++, mysql

When I am trying to select some rows from MySQL database in my C++ project I am getting an error:

```
MySQL error code: 0 MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::getInt: invalid value of 'columnIndex'
```

In the database, column "id" has datatype INT(11).

I have no problem with getting string values from others columns. I also tried to set as an argument in function getInt() both a string value - column's name, as well as a number of the column.

This is my code:

```
    preparedStatementPtr = shared_ptr < sql::PreparedStatement >( connectionPtr->prepareStatement(
            "SELECT description, category FROM plans WHERE date = ? " ) );
    string d = boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string( date );
    preparedStatementPtr->setString( 1, d );
    preparedStatementPtr->execute();
    resultSetPtr = shared_ptr < ResultSet >( preparedStatementPtr->getResultSet() );

    int id;
    string description;
    string category;

    while ( resultSetPtr->next() )
    {
        id = resultSetPtr->getInt( "id" );
        description = resultSetPtr->getString( "description" );
        category = resultSetPtr->getString( "category" );
        plans.emplace_back( std::shared_ptr < Plan >( new Plan( id, description, category, date) ) );
    }
```

What should I do to get values from the column "id"? Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** Getting id works when I don't use prepared statement, as in the following code:

```
    resultSetPtr = shared_ptr < sql::ResultSet > ( statementPtr->executeQuery (
            "SELECT * FROM plans WHERE date = '2019-05-22'" ) );


    while ( resultSetPtr->next() )
    {
        id = resultSetPtr->getInt( "id" );
        description = resultSetPtr->getString( "description" );
        category = resultSetPtr->getString( "category" );
        plans.emplace_back( std::shared_ptr < Plan >( new Plan( id, description, category, date ) ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved it. I forgot about "id" column in SELECT statement.